# Creating a Table using Memory Cells

Tags: python, assembly, compiler-construction

I'm writing my own compiler (writing in python, output is pseudo-assembly) and I'm facing a problem that I cannot solve.

I want to create a table structure using only memory cells and no registers. I can allocate enough space given the declaration, but I don't know how to refer to `tab(x)` place.

I've got `STOREN n` command, which stores main memory (which is `y_{0}` to `y_{y_{n}}`) and `LOADN n` which does reverse, so: `y_{0}` <- `y_{y_{n}}`.

Besides it, I've got

- "STORE n" `y_{n} <- y_{0}`
- "LOAD n" `y_{0} <- y_{n}`
- INC `y_{0} += 1`
- DEC `y_{0} -= 1`
- "ADD n" `y_{0} += y_{n}`
- "SUB n" `y_{0} -= y_{n}`
- "JUMP k" (jumps to another line, wrote all conditions <, >, =, !=, =>, <=)
- ^ above conditional jumps work + `JPOS k` `JZERO k` `JNEG k` that jumps to `k` if pos / zero / neg number in `y_{0}`

I already created function to set up a custom value in memory cell and one that manages for loops. Let's say that I'm storing the iterator on y_1, fromVal on y_2 and toVal on y_3, and allocated memory cells from 4 to 104 for the table tab(1:100). And now given this input...

```
let tab(1:100)
let x = 1
for i = 1 to 100:
  tab(i) = x
```

... how can I write a python code that prints out proper instructions to accomplish above code in this pseudo assembly code? I really have no hope anymore and no idea how to write a proper table managing function, that could do the task like for this example code above.

Comment: so `y_{0}` is basically a special memory location, address 0, that's like an accumulator register?  And your `y_{n}` notation means memory location `n`?  Why are there two `y_` characters in the `y_y_{n}` operand for STOREN?  Is it actually memory-indirect, like `y_{y_{n}}`?

Comment: That's all correct!
Example state:
`y_{0} = 0`,
`y_{1} = 2`,
`y_{2} = 3`. Getting command `STOREN 1` means: `p0 <- y_{y_{1}} = y_{2} = 3`